# Monthly Mortgage Payments and Amortization Table Calculation

Tags: r, amortization

I found an example code but I do not understand what the part inside the stars.

I need to replicate this link below and create a cash flow table reflecting the cash flow information:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=mortgage

My main issue is with understanding the code area inside the stars.

The Specific section of the code is below, I understand the calculations, just not the proceeding code.

```
    # Calculate Amortization for each Month
if(amort==T) {
    Pt <- P # current principal or amount of the loan
    currP <- NULL
    while(Pt>=0) {
        H <- Pt * J # this is the current monthly interest
        C <- M - H # this is your monthly payment minus your monthly interest, so it is the amount of principal you pay for that month
        Q <- Pt - C # this is the new balance of your principal of your loan
        Pt <- Q # sets P equal to Q and goes back to step 1. The loop continues until the value Q (and hence P) goes to zero
        currP <- c(currP, Pt)
    }
    monthP <- c(P, currP[1:(length(currP)-1)])-currP
    aDFmonth <<- data.frame(
                      Amortization=c(P, currP[1:(length(currP)-1)]), 
                      Monthly_Payment=monthP+c((monthPay-monthP)[1:(length(monthP)-1)],0),
                      Monthly_Principal=monthP, 
                      Monthly_Interest=c((monthPay-monthP)[1:(length(monthP)-1)],0), 
                      Year=sort(rep(1:ceiling(N/12), 12))[1:length(monthP)]
            )
    ****aDFyear <- data.frame(
                     Amortization=tapply(aDFmonth$Amortization, aDFmonth$Year, max), 
                     Annual_Payment=tapply(aDFmonth$Monthly_Payment, aDFmonth$Year, sum), 
                     Annual_Principal=tapply(aDFmonth$Monthly_Principal, aDFmonth$Year, sum), 
                     Annual_Interest=tapply(aDFmonth$Monthly_Interest, aDFmonth$Year, sum), 
                     Year=as.vector(na.omit(unique(aDFmonth$Year)))
                     )
    aDFyear <<- aDFyear
    cat("The amortization data for each of the", N, "months are stored in \"aDFmonth\".\n\n")
    cat("The amortization data for each of the", L, "years are stored in \"aDFyear\".\n\n")******
```

Comment: Hi, it seems that the question was removed. Can someone else help me out with this please?

Comment: This in not a reproducible question since only part of the script is listed here (don't expect someone to check the link).  It is not clear what your question is.  Which part don't you understand?   I would suggest deleting this question and asking a new question that is more targeted to your problem.

Comment: Just try `a <- data.frame(x=c(1,2), y=c(3,4))`. `cat` is similar to `print`. But what is your problem?

Comment: The problem is understanding the code. I want to be able to explain it as well as print it. I've updated my question above.